# Calculate limit using Stolz-Cesàro theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, harmonic-numbers

Can someone help me calculate this limit using the Stolz-Cesàro theorem?
$\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{1+\frac12+......+\frac1n}{\ln n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ln n$ is unbounded and increasing and hence we can use the theorem:
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{1+\frac12+......+\frac1n}{\ln n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{\frac1{n+1}}{\ln (n+1)-\ln n}\\
=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{\frac1{n+1}}{\ln \frac {(n+1)}n}\\
=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac1{(n+1)}-\frac 1n}\\
=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{-1}{n(n+1)}}=1\\
$$

---

This is intuitively clear because, the harmonic series can be written as:
$$
1+\frac12+......+\frac1n=\ln n+\gamma+\epsilon_n
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler constant and $\epsilon_n$ goes to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: how did you came up with -1/(n+1)^2 ?

Comment: i mean how you cam up with this? :
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{***\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}***}{\frac1{(n+1)}-\frac 1n}\\$

Comment: This is result of applying L'Hopital rule. However another way is to say $\ln\frac{n+1}{n}=\ln(1+\frac 1n) \approx \frac 1n$ when $n\to\infty$

Comment: and how from ${\ln \frac {(n+1)}n}$  you came up with = $\frac {1}{(n+1)} - \frac 1n$ ??

Comment: $\ln(\frac{x+1}{x})=\ln(x+1)-\ln x$ and I guess you know how to differentiate w.r.t. $x$. :-)

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{\frac1{n+1}}{\ln \frac {(n+1)}n}=\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{\frac {n}{n+1}}{n\ln (1+\frac {1}{n})}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac n{n+1} \frac{1}{\ln (1+\frac {1}{n})^n}$$ and use $\lim (1+\frac {1}{n})^n =e$.